# React simple fetch program run into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a simple program which receives some JSON data from a node backend and set received data into state. The problem is it reset state infinite times, creating an infinite rendering.

Here is the JSON data

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Product 1",
    "category": "C1",
    "price": "100"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Product 2",
    "category": "C1",
    "price": "80"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Product 3",
    "category": "C3",
    "price": "120"
  }
]
```

Here is the react program.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const MainApp = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/products")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {setProducts(res)})
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
    
    console.log("Products:",products) //This keep getting logged forever.

    return (
        <h1>Test</h1>
    )
}

export default MainApp
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you keep calling fetch everytime the component is re-rendered, when you update a state in React, the component gets re-rendered, and everything in the whole function is called again, you should put fetch into a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency to make sure it is only called once at the initial render of the component. You can read about `useEffect` here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fetch is continuously performed on every render of MainApp. Consider using an [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

You should only call fetch when components mounts. Since you are using hooks, you should use `

```
useEffect(()=> {
fetch("http://localhost:5000/products")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {setProducts(res)})
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
}, [])
```

`

What you are doing right now, is calling fetch on every render. Imagine it like this. You are rendering the component, during that you are fetching something and updating the state. When the state updates, it rerenders the components and you are going on an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in `{setProducts(res)}` this will update the state and  re-render the component then call the fetch function second time and so on